# How to add background image to option under select option

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-select

My currency changer is working properly how I want but I need to add background image or img tag (flag image) for each currency, I have added attr using jquery but image is not showing on front end ? but I can see in console ???

```
jQuery('#alg_currency_AED').attr('style', 'background-image:url(UAE-flag.png)');
```

here is HTML code which I can't edit, I only have option to add img or background image to option tag using jQuery or with CSS if possible.

```
<select name="alg_currency" id="alg_currency_select" class="alg_currency_select">
  <option id="alg_currency_AED" value="AED" selected="selected">د.إ AED</option>
  <option id="alg_currency_USD" value="USD">$ USD</option>
  <option id="alg_currency_GBP" value="GBP">£ GBP</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, you have to do custom code to add background image to option.

There are some steps. Following is working example that I tested before.

Hope this will help you.

https://addwebsolution.com/blog/adding-image-select-list-cross-browser-compatibility

Comment: it's working but now not changing my currencies in website